# L4260 not printing on 200 gsm specialty board

Tags: printing, inkjet-printer, epson-ecotank

I have an Epson L4260 and I'm trying to print on specialty board paper with gsm 200. But the printer is either just ignoreing the paper and letting it go through or it will report that it jammed but it doesn't look like it's jammed since I can just easily take it out. I tried *Plain Paper* and *Matte* setting but nothing works. There doesn't seem to be any option to pick the GSM value. Where do I specify the type of paper I'm using? Unfortunately I could not find what gsm specification the L4260 has. Is my printer defective or am I doing something incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: Does [this advise](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd4/cpd42858/source/printers/source/paper_loading/tasks/xp960/selecting_thick_paper_xp960.html) relate to your printer model?

Comment: Hi @harrymc I went under *Paper Source Setting > Paper Setting* where there are only 2 options for *Paper Size* and *Paper Type*. Under *Paper Type* there is no *Thick Paper* setting anywhere. Were you able to find any specs of L4260? I can't find it anywhere. It is odd for a printer company not to specify the GSM sizes their product supports. Isn't that essential information? #confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The
[User's Guide manual](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd59900/index.html),
section "Technical Specifications", sub-section
"Paper Specifications", has this line for Single-sheets:

> **Weight***  Plain paper: 17 lb (64 g/m2) to 24 lb (90 g/m2)

The asterisk says this :

> - Even if the paper thickness is within this range, the paper may not feed in the printer or the print quality may decline depending on the paper properties or quality.

The 200 gsm paper is far beyond the specs.
You may try feeding in the sheets one by one, but it's likely
to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I got in contact with customer support and apparently the thickest supported paper size is only up to 90 gsm. So unfortunately, you can't actually print with 200 gsm paper or else you may damage your printer.

[image]